# IE svg isn't showing the fill color

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, swiper.js

I'm using swiper.js for a simple slider image gallery. It uses svg for the next and previous arrows, and I've had to change the fill color to match the site I'm using it on. Firefox didn't work with the fill color using hex, so I changed it to rgb and it now works in Chrome and Firefox. Anyone know about IE's support for SVG and how to fix this? Here's the code.

```
.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-container-rtl .swiper-button-next {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 27 44'><path d='M0,22L22,0l2.1,2.1L4.2,22l19.9,19.9L22,44L0,22L0,22L0,22z' fill='rgb(138,0,0)'/></svg>");
  left: 10px;
  right: auto;
}
```

The part in question is the `fill='rgb(138,0,0)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to URL encode the data when using a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).

It's the unencoded # character in the URL that Firefox didn't like, URL encoding your make that %23.

IE is even stricter and will make you URL encode spaces (as %20).

Best stick the entire URL through an encoder, there are [plenty of online ones about](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php). Alternatively convert the data to base64.

Comment: Thank you for that I don't know much about SVG. However, I ran the whole URL through and encoder and it doesn't seem to fix my IE issue. Still works on Firefox and Chrome after using the encoded url. UPDATE: Actually I guess it's not working on chrome and firefox now. Am I supposed to encode everything between url( ) ?

Comment: Try the online tool I've added to the answer (select provide text and add the svg markup there)

Comment: @mikeLspohn: "Am I supposed to encode everything between url( ) ?"  No, don't encode the "data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8," part, just everything after that.